# Accessing constants with opaque types defined in C header from Swift

Tags: c, swift

I have a library binary (a `lib*.a` file) and the corresponding header. I have tried both the [Obj-C Bridging Header method and the Module Map method](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/23/c-libraries-swift/) to make the API available to my Swift code.

In Swift, I can access *almost* everything in the header's API. What I can't access is opaque structs, and constants with opaque structs as their type. For example, this is in the header, but Swift says the module doesn't have this member:

```
typedef struct custom_params_struct custom_params;
extern const custom_params PARAM_SET_1;
extern const custom_params PARAM_SET_2;
extern const custom_params PARAM_SET_3;
```

If I add a (fake) definition for the opaque struct and add that to my module map, like this:

```
struct custom_params_struct {
    int field_1;
    int field_2;
};
```

then the contants `PARAM_SET_1` etc are available.

Assuming I don't know the real struct definition, how do I access these consts from Swift?

Comment: Swift cannot import variables of incomplete type. The linked-to Q&A shows a possible workaround.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR for helping me find a solution. After reading the post you linked to, I was able to resolve my issue by introducing a new header that defines pointers to the consts:

    `#include "custom_params.h"`

    `static struct custom_params_struct * __nonnull PARAM_SET_1_ptr = &PARAM_SET_1;`

With this new header included in my module map, Swift now has access to PARAM_SET_1_ptr as an OpaquePointer.